# Android app rejected on Play Store due to login credentials - how to give reviewers access?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

My app has been rejected by the Play Store team because of missing login credentials. The way the app works is that you have to subscribe using Google Play to get behind the paywall. I specifically created a Google account, added it as a licence tester (so they can subscribe for free) and added the account's credentials as an instruction to the app review.

However, the app still gets rejected. Has anyone had similar experiences?

I also contacted support and asked what is wrong with my provided login credentials. As an answer I got a generic mail that explained that I must provide login credentials...

From the 1st review:

Login Credentials

In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app, and any other resources needed to review your app. In this case:

You didn’t provide an active demo/guest account or a valid username and password which we need to access your app.

From the 2nd review (this one is a huge mess, like somebody forgot to remove the points which don't apply. We don't even supported 2F auth or QR  codes):

Login Credentials

In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app, and any other resources needed to review your app. In this case:

{If a dev provided testing credential is not signing in} We could not access the in-app content with the login credentials that you have provided.
{If dev didn’t provide a demo/guest option or any login credentials to bypass the login wall} You didn’t provide an active demo/guest account or a valid username and password which we need to access your app.
{If dev didn’t provide a non-geo restricted testing credential} You didn’t provide login credentials that are valid regardless of user location which we need to access your app (for example, “master” login credentials or any instructions that will allow us to access and review the locale-specific content from any location).
{If 2 step verification blocks you from getting into the app} We are unable to bypass the 2 step verification step in your app. Please provide reusable login credentials or detailed instructions to access your app (for example, email account details where we can receive a 2 step verification code). Please note that instructions must be complete. We cannot contact you for further instructions.
{If a dev didn’t provide a QR code or barcode} You didn’t provide QR code or barcode which we need to access your app.
{If a login wall requires only biometric authentication for instance fingerprint or face scanning to login to an app} You didn’t provide Login credentials that do not require biometric authentication (for example, fingerprint or face scan) which we need to access your app.
{If the login credentials provided are non-english text characters} We are unable to use the login credentials in the language that you provided. Please provide all appropriate credentials in English via Play Console.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your entire app or parts of your app are restricted based on login credentials, sign-in details, memberships, location, or other forms of authentication. In that case, you must provide all the required details to enable access to your app.

Add instructions for app access

**1.Open Play Console and visit the App content page (Policy > App content).**

**2.Under "App access," select Start.**

**Note**: If you've previously added app access instructions and want to make changes, you'll see and select Manage instead of Start.

**3.Click + Add new instructions and provide your access details.**

**Note**: Use the "Any other instructions" field to let us know if there's anything special about your login mechanisms, such as using a one-time password, multi-factor authentication, or logins with more than two fields.

**4.Save your changes.**

Moreover, You can [follow this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?hl=en) for more details

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I also contacted support and asked what is wrong with my provided login credentials. As an answer I got a generic mail that explained that I must provide login credentials...

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue with in app app. How did you resolve it?

Comment: i think they want some credentials provided by you and not by them which is kind of stupid because you might fail the app security,